# How may i know what file or widgets in my code what i am running on my emulator

Tags: flutter

Hello I'm editing someone codes in Flutter using VS code, how can I easily find on what on I am running on my emulator. for example i am showing log in screen in the emulator. how can I know what filename did I need to edit.

as of now I am trying to check one by one of the codes. I tried to use widget tree but it is now updating

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/overview#what-can-i-do-with-devtools

Answer (score 2):

You can use the widget tree field in flutter devtool. Navigate to the desired page in the emulator and click the refresh button at the top right. The running widget stack will be listed by class names.

You can even detect a specific widget on the page using the "Choose widget mode" button.

[Install and run DevTools from VS Code](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/vscode)

[image]